# required on selectpicker based on div

Tags: validation, twitter-bootstrap-3, required, dropdown

I am learner in javaScript
How to write required on selectpicker based on

```
var typeSelectBox = "<select id='depprojsDevice' class='selectpicker'>";
typeSelectBox += "<option value=''> -- SELECT --</option>";
if (arr) {
    for (var i in arr) {
        typeSelectBox += "<option value='" + arr[i][2] + "'>" + arr[i][0] + " &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;" + arr[i][1] +  "</option>";
    }
}
typeSelectBox + "</select>";
$('#depprojsDevice_Div').html(typeSelectBox);



$("div#depprojsDevice_Div select[id = 'depprojsDevice']").attr('required','required');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
   $("#depprojsDevice").prop('required',true);
});
```

Try This Code